# get first image in wordpress repeater array

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, get

I have a while loop that gets a thumbnail and then all a bunch of other images in a div for fancybox. I need it so that when a thumb is clicked it expands first image in the repeater field of images rather than the initial thumbnail.

I tried to get the image out and echo it in but it seems to get a random image instead.

Here is my code the firstImage variable is where I am using to try get the first image from the repeater field.

Here is a link to the site http://lsmcreative.co.nz/

```
    <?php query_posts("posts_per_page=-1"); ?>
    <?php if(have_posts()):?>
    <?php $i = 0; ?>
    <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post();?> 

        <?php
        $image1ID = get_field('main');
        $image1 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image1ID, 'full-size' );
        $attachment1 = get_post( $image1ID );
        $image1_title = $attachment1->post_title;

        $categories = get_the_category(); 
        $i++;

        $firstImage = get_field('images');
        $firstImageId = $firstImage[0]['image' ]['id' ];
        $imageobject = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $firstImageId, 'full-size'  ); // returns an array
        $image_url = $imageobject[0];           
        ?>                          

            <li class="<?php foreach($categories as $category){ echo $category->category_nicename.' '; } ?>">

                <a class="grouped_elements" rel="group<?php echo $i; ?>" title="<?php echo $image_title; ?>" href="<?php echo $imageobject[0] ?>">
                    <img class="hover" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/portfolio/hover.jpg" alt="LSM Design">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image1[0] ?>" alt="<?php echo $image1_title; ?>">
                </a>

                <div class="lb-images">

                    <?php if(get_field('images')){ ?>   
                        <?php while(has_sub_field('images')): ?>
                            <?php
                            $imageID = get_sub_field('image');
                            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imageID, 'gallery-thumb' );
                            $attachment = get_post( $imageID );
                            $image_title = $attachment->post_title;
                        ?>
                        <a class="grouped_elements" rel="group<?php echo $i; ?>"  href="<?php echo $image[0] ?>" title="<?php if(get_sub_field('caption')){the_sub_field('caption');}; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[0] ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_title; ?>"></a>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php } ?>  

                </div>

            </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else: ?>  
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: can you explain which one is your repeater field and for the image what out put u are using, url, object or image id

Comment: My repeater field is called images and I am trying to get the sub field image. But I am trying to get the src of the first image in the field and use it for the src of an a tag before the if and while loop in lb images

Comment: its working fine for me i getting the first image url from the variable $image_url. while echo $image_url what value are you getting?

Comment: I get a null for some reason, there is a you can see it on the site now if you inspect the href surrounding the image

Answer (score 0):

ok give a try for this may be it will work as your firs post is giving you  the link may be due to get_posts
change ur code

```
$firstImage = get_field('images');
```

As

```
$imid=get_the_ID();
$firstImage = get_field('images',$imid);
```

hope this will work out .. :)

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to do there but it did not work :(

Comment: can you print_r( $firstImage); and post whas its returning on the section where u r not geting the image

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [image] => 80
        )

)